# Increasing the clarity in the tasks of image generation using CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, regularization, loss-functions, image-processing, gan

What methods exist to improve the quality of generated images and the clarity of contours in the tasks of image denoising/debluring (using CNN), style transfer etc? I am interested in approaches that don't change network architecture and dataset (maybe special loss function?). Are there any articles devoted to this problem?